# What is wrong with for loop syntax?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, statements

I have this piece of code down here - the `PlayingDeck` class. It's not done, as you see, but what happens is that on line 17, Right under the for loop, I get an error message saying the `PlayingCard` declaration and initialization isn't a statement. Why so? When I add the curly brackets to the for loop with just that same statement, the error message disappears. Could someone please explain why? All I need are two brackets, one at the start and one at the end of the for loop...?

Thank you

Code that does not compile --------

```
public class PlayingDeck {
    static int numberOfCards;

    static {
        numberOfCards = 52;
    }

    PlayingCard[] playingDeckArray;

    PlayingDeck() {
        playingDeckArray = new PlayingCard[numberOfCards];

        for (int currentCardNumber = 0; currentCardNumber > 51; currentCardNumber++)
            PlayingCard currentCard = playingDeckArray[currentCardNumber];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Code that Compiles -----

```
public class PlayingDeck {
    static int numberOfCards;

    static {
        numberOfCards = 52;
    }

    PlayingCard[] playingDeckArray;

    PlayingDeck() {
        playingDeckArray = new PlayingCard[numberOfCards];

        for (int currentCardNumber = 0; currentCardNumber > 51; currentCardNumber++){
            PlayingCard currentCard = playingDeckArray[currentCardNumber];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed because the declaration of `PlayingCard currentCard` has no scope if you don't wrap it with braces.

BTW, if you want your loop to do something, you should probably change the condition to `currentCardNumber < 51`;

Comment: Is it fair to say that it has a scope, but that scope is useless?

Comment: Or even change the condition to `currentCardNumber < numberOfCards`.

Comment: I guess that make sense because when I do this for loop everything compiles just fine:

`PlayingDeck() {
        DeckArray = new PlayingCard[numOfSuits][numOfRanks];
        for (int currentSuitNumber = 1; currentSuitNumber <= numOfSuits; currentSuitNumber++) {
            for (int currentRankNumber = 1; currentRankNumber <= numOfRanks; currentRankNumber++)
                DeckArray[currentSuitNumber - 1][currentRankNumber - 1] = new PlayingCard(currentSuitNumber, currentRankNumber);
        }
    }`

But there is no variable declaration here so I guess curly brackets aren't necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `for loop`

```
for (int currentCardNumber = 0; currentCardNumber > 51; currentCardNumber++)
            PlayingCard currentCard = playingDeckArray[currentCardNumber];
}
```

The opening curly brace `{` is missing.

That's a standard for any language, not only java. Any loop, whether it be `for loop`, or `while loop` or `do-while loop`, or any block like `if-else`, `if-else if- else`, `switch` must have opening and closing curly braces.

Read this for more details: [Control Flow Statements in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)

Also read this: [Wikipedia - Indent Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)